# Why is Imported class not found in PHP file?

Tags: php, class, composer-php, repository, packagist

I'm attempting to use a class from a repository I installed from packagist with composer. The PHP file I'm writing is under my `Project` folder, along with the repository which is in `Project>vendor`.

```
include "Project/vendor/autoload.php";
include "Project/vendor/smartcat/smartcat-api/src/SmartCAT/API/SmartCAT.php";


use SmartCAT\API\SmartCAT;
use SmartCAT\API\Model\CreateProjectWithFilesModel;
```

This is at the top of my file and it is how I'm retrieving the smartcat class from the repository. When I try to use the class I wrote `$sc= new SmartCAT($login, $password);`. This causes the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SmartCAT\API\SmartCAT' not found in C:\Users\...\Project\createProject.php:20`. When I run `get_included_files()` the necessary files are included. I'm not sure why I'm unable to use the class.

Comment: You use composer, there's no need to include other files except `autoload.php`.

Comment: I removed that line and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you add your classpath to composer.json either `classmap` or `psr-4`?

Comment: My composer. json looks like '{
    "require": {
        "smartcat/smartcat-api": "^2.0"
    }
}
' How would I add the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `vendor/autoload.php` path in the `include` directive?

If your `createProject.php` file and `vendor` folders are located in the same folder, you need to use `include "vendor/autoload.php";`